# Convert string "2017-01-01T12:00:33:123456Z+02" to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

i am trying to convert this string i get from the customer to a datetime, to store it in my db.

i tried several approches but nothing seems to work.
i need the offset in UTC time so i guess i need to do something with zz.

This is working:

```
string   test = "2008-06-11T16:11:20.0904778Z";
DateTime publishingTimeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But the string by the customer is slightly different, so i tried this one:

```
string   test = "2017-01-01T12:00:33:123456Z+02"; 
DateTime publishingTimeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:ffffffzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Unfortunaly it is not working. How can i convert the exact string "2016-01-01T10:00:55:123456Z+02"? Is it even possible because it uses ":" in front of ffffff

Thank you

Comment: *"...it is not working"* How? What result do you get and what result do you expect? Do you get an error? If yes, which one?

Comment: Why `ParseExact`? You can use simple `DateTime.Parse(test, out dt)`. With ISO string it does not need culture, format, etc.

Comment: No, that was [my initial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36572742/993547) but the format deviates from that format too much @i486

Comment: You use `Z+02` at the end. Normally the UTC offset is instead of the `Z`, as Z means UTC or +00. Are you sure there is a `Z` before the offset?

Comment: Indeed, that date format is invalid @Wimmel That is why I deleted my answer. The customer of OP should use standard formatting for dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you forget to escape `Z` as a string literal delimiter in your format as `'Z'`.

```
string test = "2017-01-01T12:00:33:123456Z+02";
DateTime publishingTimeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(test, 
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:ffffff'Z'zz", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
Console.WriteLine(publishingTimeStamp); // 01.01.2017 12:00:33
```

But since your string has [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, I would parse it to `DateTimeOffset` instead.

```
string test = "2017-01-01T12:00:33:123456Z+02";
DateTimeOffset publishingTimeStamp = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(test, 
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:ffffff'Z'zz", 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                     DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{01.01.2017 12:00:33 +02:00}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i really had a mess with the 'Z'zz. You saved my day!

Comment: Do note that at least the `:` also should be escaped unless specifying the culture properly. Otherwise it may alter the interpretation.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Exactly. That's why I used `InvariantCulture` since it _already_ has `:` string as a `TimeSeparator`.